# How to make viewModel lifecycle work for AndroidX-Lifecycle-viewModel-SavedState (with Jetpack Compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel-savedstate

My setup (relevant subset):

- **Android Gradle Plugin** 7.1.2
- **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate** 2.4.1
- **androidx.activity:activity-compose** 1.4.0
- **androidx.compose.*** 1.2.0-alpha04
- **androidx.navigation:navigation-compose** 2.4.1

I am trying to persist UI state by enhancing the capabilities of my activity-bound `ViewModel` to leverage lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate. Basically it looks like this:

```kotlin
class MySavedStateViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() { 

   init {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           // Logic to load data from savedStateHandle
       }
   } 

   fun saveData() {
       // Logic to save data to savedStateHandle
   }

}
```

I create the `ViewModel` within a composable, which looks like this:

```kotlin
val mySavedStateViewModel: MySavedStateViewModel by activityBoundViewModel(
     factoryProducer = {
        MySavedStateViewModelFactory(context as ComponentActivity)
     }
)
```

MySavedStateViewModelFactory looks like this:

```kotlin
class MySavedStateViewModelFactory(
    savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    bundle: Bundle? = null
) :
    MySavedStateViewModelFactory(savedStateRegistryOwner, bundle) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
        val viewModel = MySavedStateViewModel(savedStateHandle = handle)
        return viewModel as T
    }

}
```

It looks like savedStateHandle is updated properly when using the app but when I kill it and start it again the data is lost.

**What do I need to change to make persistance work?**

Related but an old post: [SavedState ViewModel Using SavedStateViewModelFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728260/savedstate-viewmodel-using-savedstateviewmodelfactory)

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood the capabilities of SavedState. At least "OnSavedInstanceState" doesn't seem to be saving state at all according to https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options

Survives user complete activity dismissal/onFinish() - No